# Tabs on overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Been looking everywhere for a tutorial.  I want to create an overlay with tabs like how Google Chrome webstore does it. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boemmnepglcoinjcdlfcpcbmhiecichi

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or a combination of tutorials that would achieve this results?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? E.g. did you try to use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), and get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabs for Twitter Bootstrap look clean and you won't have to restyle much to go for the Google look.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

You can use jQueryUI tabs but you'll have to style them quite a bit to look like the Google page.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll check it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS with rollover tags instead.

i.e.: http://unraveled.com/publications/css_tabs/

Alternatively use Javascript

e.g.: http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/

Comment: That won't work unless you put the overlay in an `<iframe>`, which IMHO is not a real solution.

Comment: I want to do the same thing.  I understand how to create the tabs and modal box individually, but how do you combine them as in the OP's first question?  Thanks